# specify a location of a view without using margin in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and currently having some issues with layout. Here is my problem:

```
View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.MiddleMan);
view.layout(240,358,240+view.getWidth(),358+view.getHeight());
```

width is 2 dp, height is match_parent. This view is inside a relative_layout, which is inside a linear_layout. This coordinates are relative to linear_layout

When I run, instead of being exactly at this coordinate, it keeps sticking to the right edge of the parent. Can anyone show me how I can deal with this problem, pls ? Appreciate a lot

Comment: Place it in the xml view editor and see what attributes are getting set. Then you can do you it on run time.

Comment: Do it in xml bro

Comment: I cannot do it in xml because the position here can be changed in any devices. I have to extract the width of the screen and divide it by three

Comment: use LinearLayout  with atribute of android:weightSum, eg. weightSum = 3. inside each child layout sum = 1, it will extractly divide your layout by three in any given screen size

Comment: Your idea is correct but impractical to my program, that is why I have to search for another way